# How to properly close a NodeJS to MySQL connection?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am programming a NodeJS server with express and MySQL. This server is only supposed to work a a Rest API, providing JSON data to a mobile app and a Angular front-end application.

I'm currently making a connection to the database using the mysql npm module. I am noticing an increasing amount of threads everytime I reload my application since they are not closing. The reason for that is that I start the connection when I first start the server. 
I am wondering if my coding approach is actually the best or if in due time the connection will be interrupted if many people start accessing it.

In the end what I want to know is if I should be:
1) Making the HTTP request
2) Opening the connection
3) Retrieving the data
4) Closing the connection after the data is retrieved.

Or if I should keep my approach of:
1) Starting the connection when the service is started
2) Using that reference to make all requests/responses

Code of how I'm doing it now:

db_config.ts

```
    import mysql from 'mysql';
import DevTools from '../dev_tools/devtools';

export function connectToDatabase(): any {

    let connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3306,
        user: 'userapp',
        password: 'app!@#',
        database: 'db_app'
    })

    connection.connect((err) => {
        if (err) {
            DevTools.printIfInDevMode('DATABASE', `  ${err.code} - Error while connecting:  ${err.name} - ${err.message} `)
            return;
        }
        DevTools.printIfInDevMode('DATABASE', `Connected with id ${connection.threadId}`)

        return connection;
    })
}
```

server_config.ts

```
    import express from "express";
import DevTools from "../dev_tools/devtools";
const app = express();

//Configuração para receber parâmetros via POST
app.use(express.urlencoded(
    {
        extended: true
    }
));
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    DevTools.printIfInDevMode('SERVER', 'Chegou aqui')
    res.send(req.body);
})

export default app;
```

server_start.ts

```
    // node-typescript/src/entry.ts
import app from './server_config';
import { connectToDatabase } from './db_config';

export default function startServer() {
    app.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log(`[SERVER] Servidor Iniciado `);
        connectToDatabase();

    });
}
```

app_dev.ts

```
    import startServer from './config/server_start';
import DevTools from './dev_tools/devtools';

console.log("[SERVER] Starting in developer mode")
DevTools.setDevMode(true);
startServer();
```

What happens basically:

1. I use npm run on **app_dev.ts**
2. **app_dev.ts** makes the application run in developer mode which allows
   me to easily debug via the "printIfInDevMode" method.
3. It calls the "startServer" method which is imported from
   **server_start.ts**
4. **server_start.ts** imports the app variable from **server_config.ts** which
   contains the configuration for the express service.
5. **server_start.ts** executes the listen method on port 3000 and after
   that tries to connect to the database via the "connectToDatabase"
   method imported from **db_config.ts**
6. The "connectToDatabase" method simply starts a connection to a MySQL
   server running on the localhost and return an error if it fails to
   do so.
7. If it succeeds, it prints out the ThreadId of the connection.

I'm wondering if I should keep the "connectToTheDatabase" method inside the app.listen(3000) and never close this connection, or if I should put it inside the GET routes, opening a connection when someone acesses that route, retrieving the data and then closing the connection.

Answer (score 0):

From the mysql npm page/documentation,

> Closing the connection is done using end() which makes sure all remaining queries are executed before sending a quit packet to the mysql server.

So you would likely do something like `connection.end()` to achieve what you want, that is assuming that open connections are indeed the problem.
It would help in situations like this to share a bit of your code.

Comment: OK, wilco. Could check back in just a bit?

Comment: Alright, just added the code of the application. Its pretty simple since I have just started programming it